Is it appropriate to call trough cross-stratification a 'bedform'?
This is a somewhat inane question of semantics, but words are important in science, so I ask: is it appropriate to call trough cross-stratification a 'bedform'?
The Blatt et al (1980) definition says bedforms are sedimentary structures created by fluid systems working on sandy sediment. In other words bedforms are the product of sediment interacting with the geometry of some turbulent flow, sediment size and shape working alongside flow speed, turbulence, and directionality to produce some characteristic (although maybe non-unique) arrangement of said sediment.
Would it be more accurate then to consider cross stratification, lamination, or bedding as the product of the deposition of these bedforms and therefore not bedforms themselves? Or, because these arrangements are again the product of successive generations of depositional arrangement in response to some flow, are they also bedforms? What do you all think.
